# Scrollbar within a scrollbar only make the inner scrollbar jump to id

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, page-jump

I have a page that requires a scrollbar -

http://www.aus-media.com/dev/site_BYJ/schedule-pricing/pricing.html

You will notice (unless you are running at a high resolution with a big screen) that there is an outer scrollbar for the main page as well as an inner scrollbar for the content. When you click on one of the sub items e.g. payments you will notice that the outer page scrolls down as well as the inner scrollbar.

Does anybody know of a way to only scroll the inner scrollbar, so only it jumps to the id?

Thanks guys
Nik

Answer (score 1):

browser try to scroll up until target is on top, to achieve this, both scrollbars need to scroll.

You should use javascript to scroll only inner scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks Lauri, I found this link which seems to be what I need. http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/